# How do you run kakorokuRecorder on Wine?

Tags: linux, wine

I'm trying to run kakorokuRecorder on Wine but I get this when I run it.

```
System.ArgumentException: A null reference or invalid value was found [GDI+ status: InvalidParameter]
      at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (Status status) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Drawing.Image.get_FrameDimensionsList () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Image:get_FrameDimensionsList ()
      at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.CanAnimate (System.Drawing.Image image) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.PictureBox_HandleCreated (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnHandleCreated (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnHandleCreated (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    Shutting down finalizer thread timed out.
```

This is a simple program so it should work fine on wine, I think?

Answer (score 1):

This program isn't listed on [WineHQ](http://www.winehq.org/), and I can't find anywhere else someone has gotten this program to work.

A lot of programs will not run in Wine if they rely heavily on .NET without doing some tweaks and manual configuration of Wine. If you don't have the ability to do these things, you'll probably have to wait until it's supported, or find an alternative program.